# Movesense, setting the system time

Tags: movesense

I am trying to set the system time in Movesense. I couldn't find an example of that, but based on the documentation I think that this should do:

```
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::TIME(),
     AsyncRequestOptions::Empty,
     (int64_t)0);
```

In this case, I'm just trying to reset the epoch to zero but `onPutResults` gives me

> HTTP_CODE_BAD_REQUEST

So what is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum timestamp seems to be 1483228800000000 us which corresponds to 1.1.2017. So you can't set the time to 70's as zero would set it to.
This should be documented in the yaml api but currently is not. We will add that to the list of tasks to make sure it's documented in the next release of device-lib.