# Unable to set system time

Tags: movesense

I'm trying to synchronize multiple sensors as described in Movesense developer workshop (https://youtu.be/GGMXJ8FWMSw?t=4335) by setting the system time. For some reason the following method to set system time does not work and onPutResult gives me error.

```
 //Example value
 int64_t utcTimestamp = 1619510994204;

 asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::TIME(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, utcTimestamp);
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I misread the documentations, time value must be passed as microseconds instead of milliseconds. Minimum time value is 1483228800000000 as answered here ->
[Movesense, setting the system time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322428/movesense-setting-the-system-time)